Why am I getting "Unsafe assignment of an `any` value" although the value was defined as a string with default value
The following code shows 2 eslint errors, and I don't understand why. The property is defined as a string with the default value:
export default {
  name: '...',
  props: {
    x: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
    onMounted(async () => {
      await MyObject(
        {
          x: props.x, // <-- eslint warnings
        }
      ).then(...);

The 2 eslint warnings are:

Unsafe assignment of an any value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
Unsafe member access .initialDoc on an any value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access

The MyObject is defined in an external library like this:
declare const MyObject: MyObject;
// ...
declare type MyObject = {
    (options: MyObjectOptions): Promise<...>
// ...
export type MyObjectOptions = {
  x?: string | string[];
}

So it looks like types are well defined everywhere. Why does it trigger the eslint warnings then?

can you try this:
import { PropType } from 'vue';

props: {
   x: {
      type: String as PropType<string>,
      required: true
   }
}

ps: you don't need default value if prop is required

this was a helpful suggestion, it led me to look properly into typed properties, which has a direct answer to my question

The solution is to use defineComponent as this doc page defines:

If not using <script setup>, it is necessary to use defineComponent() to enable props type inference. The type of the props object passed to setup() is inferred from the props option.

So in my case all I needed was:
export default defineComponent ({
  name: '...',
  props: {
    x: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
    // ...
});

Notice that, as @BorisMaslennikov suggested, the default is not needed.
